# AWS Codestar Setup Beanstalk Policy Errors for Auto-scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, autoscaling, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codestar

I've been trying to use Codestar on AWS Ruby on Rails using Elastic Beanstalk. I tried applying and assigning auto scaling full access policies to no avail. Can anybody help me navigate around these errors? Also using root account. Tried assigning this under roles but no success.

Error messages:

```
Creating Auto Scaling group failed Reason: API: autoscaling:CreateAutoScalingGroup The default Service-Linked Role for Auto Scaling could not be created. com.amazonaws.services.identitymanagement.model.AmazonIdentityManagementException: 
User: arn:aws:sts::**********:assumed-role/CodeStarWorker-phcnetworks-net-CloudFormation/AWSCloudFormation is not authorized to perform: iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::**************:role/aws-service-role/autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling 
(Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: *******-******-*******)

Stack named 'awseb-e-*********-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBAutoScalingGroup].
```

Comment: Can you verify if role CodeStarWorker-phcnetworks-net-CloudFormation has proper IAM action aiam:CreateServiceLinkedRole defined ?

Comment: The aiam:CreateServiceLinkedRole is not defined.

Comment: Can you add it and try again?

Comment: Thanks bdcloud your suggestion worked like a charm. Everything running now. Really appreciate it. If you put a simple answer below can give you credit.

Comment: Awesome.Thanks for the confirmation.I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reported error says that the role "CodeStarWorker-phcnetworks-net-CloudFormation" is not authorized to perform operation iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole on the set of resources defined in IAM policy.So action "CreateServiceLinkedRole" needs to be added to the role for your autoscaling policies to succeed.